# ??(null-coalescing operator) between EF6 Queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities

I am developing an MVC 5 app using EF 6. I want to query my database and store a value in a variable and if there is null as per the the given condition then another query should be executed to return a value. In my method I have as follows: D1 is coming as a parameter and it has the current date.

```
int otherYear = D1.Year + 1;
lastNo = (db.ABC.ToList().LastOrDefault(x => x.D1.Value.Month <= 6 && x.D1.Value.Year == otherYear).S1) ?? (db.ABC.ToList().LastOrDefault(x => x.D1.Value.Month > 6 && x.D1.Value.Year == D1.Year).S1);
```

Now the first query before `??` operator executes but when there is null against the condition specified the system throws an error of object reference and does not execute the second query after `??` operator. How can I solve it?

I know that it can be solved by making an if-else condition and within that I should first check that if there is any data using `.Any()` function. But in that case I have to query my database for minimum of 2 times. Once in `.Any()` to check the availability of data and second to fetch that data. But I have a hefty database and I don't want to make extra queries.

Regards

Comment: `the system throws an error of object reference` for witch object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call `db.ABC.ToList()` before applying `LastOrDefault()` because it will load the whole database to memory and do the processing from there.

You're getting null reference exception because `db.ABC.LastOrDefault(x => x.D1.Value.Month <= 6 && x.D1.Value.Year == otherYear)` is null so that you cannot get `S1` property.

For your question, I think you can use this code:

```
int otherYear = D1.Year + 1;
lastNo = (db.ABC.LastOrDefault(x => x.D1.Value.Month <= 6 && x.D1.Value.Year == otherYear)?.S1) ?? (db.ABC.LastOrDefault(x => x.D1.Value.Month > 6 && x.D1.Value.Year == D1.Year)?.S1);
```

Comment: When I didn't use .Abc.ToList() it gives me error  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '.Models.ABC LastOrDefault[ABC](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[.Models.ABC], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[.Models.ABC,System.Boolean]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the double query issue, store the result of the query in a list:

```
int otherYear = D1.Year + 1;
List<T> myABC = db.ABC.ToList();
lastNo = (myABC.LastOrDefault(x => x.D1.Value.Month <= 6 && x.D1.Value.Year == otherYear).S1) ?? (myABC.LastOrDefault(x => x.D1.Value.Month > 6 && x.D1.Value.Year == D1.Year).S1);
```